# Update of Tensor Flow Lite model on mobile without app update?

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to update / replace a currently existing Tensor Flow Lite model on a deployed mobile app?

I would like to:

- Deploy an app with a default model
- Update the TF model via server once a significant amount of new data has been collected, uploaded and used to retrain (on the server)

Without updating the entire app.

What is the current best practice for accomplishing this? Are there gotchas?

Comment: Is there any update to this question? I'm also trying to deploy an app to both iOS and Android. But I'm not sure if it's possible to update the model anytime we want, or we have to wait for an app update to update our model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish update only the model and the  entire app then you can use [Firebase MLKit](https://firebase.google.com/products/ml-kit/) to distribute .tflite models.

- The app will download the new model as soon you update it in the console.
- You can implement various such models.

For deploying the models visit this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models).